# MS excel converting text value to scientific exponential

Tags: excel

today i have created text file later covert it into a MS excel file with data in a column like

```
4045E00091
4045E00095
```

when the file is in text format the data is same
but when i change extension of file to `xls` or `csv` then the data becomes like

```
4.045E+94
4.045E+98
```

It seems like excel thinks that they are representing some exponential format, but its not so. I have bunch of cols in my file and this one is creating the problem. please share any solution for this.

Comment: what is the format of your cell in the new file?

Comment: Its scientific.. But i tried all the formats but didn't worked...

Comment: Have you tried preceding the data with a single quote (`'`) character?

Comment: @MarkBannister Actual definitely works but it increase my headache of removing quotes after that for bunch of data and columns

Answer (score 0):

Excel shortens large numbers into these sort of values if large numbers are entered into text fields.

to fix this: 
Click the column to highlight all cells.
Then right click and select format cells.
Select number from the list on the left
Set the number of decimal places to 0.
Click okay and your values should now all be the full numbers

Comment: its converting data to large number with no. of zeroes like `40450000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.......            `

Comment: You will be better off using a seperate software called Open Office (open office calc is the spreadsheet software). It is not very nicely presented but it will not alter your data in the way which excel is. When working with CSV files this is the software which i alwasy reccomend. Please try this and let me know the outcome [OPEN OFFICE DOWNLOAD](https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods suggested by Microsoft that may help:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214233/en-us

The two answers that may work for you would include formatting as text before saving as xls, or adding the apostrophe at the beginning of the column.

It will also keep the correct format when you save as CSV. In fact, in my testing, even the single quote option works when you save as CSV, and the quote is stripped out when you view the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Append a tab character("\t") to the string which is been converted to scientific format. Any special character will do eh good. But since we don't need to appear that in field, we should use "\t".

Answer (score 0):

use =Trim() to convert value from exponential format back to text

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).